# Code does not compile and shows ambiguous message

Tags: swiftui

I have this code:

```
enum MenuOptions {
  case play, stop, none
}


struct MyView: View {
  typealias runOnLongPressItemHandler = (ScrollItem, MenuOptions)->Void
  var runOnLongPressItem: runOnLongPressItemHandler?

  var scrollItems:[ScrollItem]

  init(var scrollItems:[ScrollItem],
       _ runOnLongPressItem: runOnLongPressItemHandler?) {
    self.scrollItems = scrollItems
    self.runOnLongPressItem = runOnLongPressItem
  }

  var body: some View {
    ScrollView (showsIndicators:true) {    
      ForEach(scrollItems, id: \.self) { scrollItem in
        ValidationListSubItem(scrollItem)
          .contextMenu {
             Button {
              runOnLongPressItemHandler?(scrollItem, .play) //1
             } label: {
               Label("play", systemImage: "play.circle")
             }
              
             Button {
              runOnLongPressItemHandler?(scrollItem, .stop) //
             } label: {
               Label("play", systemImage: "play.circle")
             }
           }   
         }
       }
```

This will not compile will this nonsense line

> The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

but if I comment lines //1 and //2 it compiles fine.

This is ScrollItem

```
struct ScrollItem: Identifiable, Hashable {
  let id = UUID()
  var iconType:Icon = .none
  var description:String = ""
}
```

Why?

Comment: Can you show code for `ScrollItem` and `scrollItems`?

Comment: I have added the info.

Comment: What is the type `runOnLongPressItemHandler`? Also, it is proper to capitalize type names to differentiate them from an instance of the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling your `runOnLongPressItemHandler` typealias (doesn't make sense) instead of calling your `runOnLongPressItem` closure. And as [Yrb said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68716711/code-does-not-compile-and-shows-lame-message/68717061#comment121441788_68716711), you should capitalize `RunOnLongPressItemHandler`. Replace:

```
runOnLongPressItemHandler?(scrollItem, .play)
runOnLongPressItemHandler?(scrollItem, .stop)
```

with

```
runOnLongPressItem?(scrollItem, .play)
runOnLongPressItem?(scrollItem, .stop)
```